# Node.js MySQL routes + model structure

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, model-view-controller

Hello I am new to building node js and express web applications and am trying to understand how to structure route handling + model code using MySQL and node.js. Here is an example of my current login.

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {

    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?';

    checkUsername();

    function checkUsername() {
        connection.query(sqlQuery,[email], function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) return next(error);

            if(results.length == 0) {
                res.status(401).json({ message: 'invalid credentials' });
            } else {
                checkPassword(results[0].password, results[0]);
            }
        });
    }

    function checkPassword(hash, result) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, match) {
            if (match) {
                var userToken = jwt.sign({id: result.id}, config.JWTSecret, { expiresIn: '1h' });
                delete result.password;
                res.status(200).json({token: userToken, user_data: result});
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({ message: 'invalid credentials' });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

as you can see currently all of the logic is being performed in the route handler. What is the advantage of extracting this code to a model object? Should the response be sent in the model or route handler? How would you structure your code for this particular example using a user object and more generally when using MVC with express and MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: you should take a look at express-generator, sequelize and passport (for authentication). Express-generator itself gives you a good base to start your project in terms of organization